# Understanding SUSY, Lie groups, gauge theory, etc

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, standard-model, gauge-theory

We are currently learning about the Standard Model, but we had no lectures on the above topics, therefore it is very hard for me to understand how symmetries play a role in the Standard Model and why they  are important.

So I'm asking for books or videos or PDFs that help me understand things like Lie groups, gauge theory, super symmetry, continuous and discrete symmetries, symmetry breaking, and so on and also explain how these concepts are related to each other, offering a fundamental understanding of these concepts, and also a geometrical interpretation for them if possible.

Comment: Why does it look like I asked this question? All I did was edit it.

Comment: @G. Smith, at 50k reputation you should really know better than to ask such a broad question...

Comment: Ugh. If I can’t fix this I’ll just stop editing questions.

Comment: I think it became “community wiki” while I was editing it. @imbAF, please edit your question so that *your* name appears.

Comment: @G.Smith Community wikis shows the name of the user with the "largest" contribution to the post in the "author" position. I'm not sure how that computation works, but even after my recent edit it seems to think (*"8 revs, 4 users 37%"*) you've written more than a third of this post. Complaints about this mechanism should be raised on [meta.SE], there's nothing we local moderators can do about it, sorry.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Thank you for trying.